# Switching User-Agent in Opera

Tags: opera, user-agent

How can the [user agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) be changed in Opera?

The per-site preferences (tab *Network*, field *Browser identification*) lists

- Identify as Opera
- Identify as Firefox
- Identify as Internet Explorer
- Masquerade as Firefox
- Masquerade as Internet Explorer

But can it be set to an arbitrary string (for example, `googleinstantisreallyirritating`)?

Opera version: 11.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Opera 12 there is a new option for an arbitrary string: Open `opera:config#UserPrefs|CustomUser-Agent` in the address bar, enter the desired string and click on *Save* at the bottom of the page. The change will apply without restart.

Or you could use the extension https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/user-agent-changer/ which makes it a little bit easier.

Comment: The custom config you suggest does not exist, neither the extension... This answer should not be market as acceptable or must be updated!

Answer (score 3):

[Opera support document](http://www.opera.com/support/usingopera/operaini/#ua) indicates this is not possible. The possible choices are the numeric identifiers, which correspond to each user agent mentioned in the question.

<strike>[This comment](http://dev.opera.com/forums/topic/218818?t=1309023117&page=1#comment3812841)</strike> (admittedly, over a year old) by an Opera employee also confirms the same.

*Update:* the article is down, but source code has been archived to Github--here's [a related article](https://github.com/operasoftware/devopera-static-backup/blob/master/http/dev.opera.com/articles/view/building-opera-nalakuvara-part-2/index.html#L1230).

Comment: Bad news: the comment is 404. Awesome news: the whole forum (and more) is archived at [github!](https://github.com/operasoftware/devopera-static-backup/)